# can I use both DFD and ERD

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema, erd

I just came across DFD while reading paper I know how to use ERD and I've read about DFD. However can I use both DFD and ERD to represent my database design can I use both ERD & DFD to represent my database in project.

Answer (score 5):

Data flow diagrams describe communication of data whereas entity-relationship diagrams describe structure of data.  Thus, these two types of diagrams are orthogonal and together they describe a system more completely than either does on its own.

The DFD normally has greater scope, depicting communication among multiple data stores or agents.  ERDs can be used to model the state of each element as well as the semantics of messages between them.

Comment: is it like use case but for database ?

Comment: No, use cases focus on actions.  DFDs focus on the flow of data between components, some of which may be databases.